# Will I get leavers penalty, even after rejoining the same game?

Tags: overwatch

I usually play with my friends in a group, and it can happen that i'm either quickly afk or get a disconnect due to my router spasing out. My question is, does that "leave" still count as one if i rejoin the same game (through either a group invite from a friend or manually joining)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as soon as you leave you get the penalty, regardless of if you rejoin.